# Use iCheck checkbox plugin on Ember.js 2.6 and ember-cli

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I want to use iCheck checkboxes in Ember.js 2.6.0 application with ember-cli and pod structure.

How I can extend this input helper like

```
{{input type="checkbox" name="isAdmin" checked=isAdmin}}
```

for automatically convert this to iCheck checkboxes for all pages?

Link to iCheck:

https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading following docs:

- [Ember Checkbox helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_checkbox)
- [Ember Checkbox class](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Checkbox.html)

and then either wrapping templates in your own component or reopening the checkbox class to add additional class names or other attributes.

Comment: Can you clarify bit more?